# Line break after \section number

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking

I need to have a line break after `\section` number (I use Roman numbers), like:

```
I
Section

... some text ...

II
Section
```

I've tried `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}\\}`, but it only creates errors.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT: CODE SAMPLE**

I use modified template from TexWorks

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\geometry{margin=1.5cm}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{}\chead{}\rhead{}
\lfoot{}\cfoot{\thepage}\rfoot{}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\centering}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 


\title{titlee}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit

\end{document}
```

Comment: what class do you use? please show us a minimal example of your code.

Comment: I use `\documentclass{article}`

Comment: may be `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}`

Comment: oh sorry I didn't understand the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one option using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesection}{0pt}{}

\begin{document}

\section{A test numbered section}
Some test text.
\section*{A test unnumbered section}
Some test text.
\section{Another test numbered section}
Some test text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: not a good idea (see comments)**

A little solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\sect}[1]{\section{\newline #1}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}

\sect{foo}

\sect{bar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This also "wrecks" the ToC.

Comment: And invalidates the optional argument for `\section`.

Comment: @Werner @GonzaloMedina : You're right didn't thought about it `:/`