# "There's no line to break" after a \\ in \titleformat

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec

I have problems when trying to compile a document with `\section` modified. I wrote the following code for my format:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\titleformat{\section}{\centering \bf \Large}{Título}{0.3em}{\thesection\\}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
```

But, after the titlepage, I insert a \tableofcontents which is throwing the error: `LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.`

I tried replacing the `\\` from the `\titleformat` with `\newline` but the result is not what I need (that does not throw the error).

The question: Is there any simple way I can get this output when writing `\section{I'm a Title!}`?

[image: Needed output]

EDIT: Sample Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\titleformat{\section}{\centering \bf \Large}{Título}{0.3em}{\thesection\\}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{I'm a Title!}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I just added a short code to see the output. I'm using `\documentclass{article}`btw

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that your code doesn't work correctly with unnumbered sectioning headers, i.e., those produced by `\section*`?

Comment: @Mico yes I'm aware, but all my sections will be numbered. Thanks!

Comment: @MAubel - I guess the good news is that the code in my answer works with both numbered and unnumbered sections. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(revised my answer after coming across the posting [Line break after \section number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/273020/5001))

The following code is based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273024/5001) to the query [Line break after \section number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/273020/5001). The solution lies in changing the arguments of `\titleformat`. Specifically, instead of

```
\titleformat{\section}{\centering \bf \Large}{Título}{0.3em}{\thesection\\}
```

you should write

```
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{Título \thesection}{0.3em}{}
```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[display]%
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{Título \thesection}{0.3em}{}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{I'm a Title!}
\subsection{And I'm a Subtitle!}
\end{document}
```