# Adding titles in exam class

Tags: exam

I want to add sections and titles for questions in exam class. I used report class
but I am wondering if I can get something similar with exam class . I want something like this (se also the picture),

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4pape]{exam} % 'twoside' when printing
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, twoside]{geometry}
\linespread{1.3}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % UTF-8 input
\usepackage[english]{babel}             % Set language to english
\usepackage{blindtext}                  % Use \Blinddocument or \blindmathpaper
\usepackage{graphicx,graphics}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{color,xcolor,colortbl}  
\usepackage{cite}
\graphicspath{ {/Users/farha/Documents} }
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{url}                    
\usepackage{hyperref}
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,mathtools,physics,bm}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow,multicol,tabularx,floatrow,float,makecell,hhline,arydshln}                            
\usepackage{gensymb}                                                                    
\usepackage{parskip}                                
\usepackage[sharp]{easylist}        
\usepackage{makeidx,listings,tikz-cd,enumitem}              
%\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}                                      
\usepackage[expansion=false]{microtype} 
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}                                                                     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{xpatch,lipsum,framed,etoolbox}
\usepackage{geometry,array,subcaption}  
\usepackage{placeins,afterpage} 
\usepackage{textcomp,siunitx} % to get celsisus degree
\usepackage{pdfpages} % add pdf pages
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames*,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    %\tableofcontents
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth ]
    \section*{PART 1\\
         Without help tools}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{questions}
 \question Assignment 1 (5 points) 

Let f  be a function given by  $f(x)=x^{3}+\pi x+4$
\begin{parts}
\part 
\part
\part 
\end{parts}
 \question Assignment 2 (5 points)

\begin{parts}
    \part 
    \part
    \part 
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidtt]
\section*{PART 2 \\
    With help tools}    
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{questions}
    \question Assignment 1 (5 points) 
    
    Let f  be a function given by  $f(x)=x^{3}+\pi x+4$
    \begin{parts}
        \part 
        \part
        \part 
    \end{parts}
    \question Assignment 2 (5 points)
    
    \begin{parts}
        \part 
        \part
        \part 
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See section 6.2 of the exam class manual.  Graphical `\part` titles are tricky, by not uncommon.

Answer (score 1):

First, the right usage is not

```latex
\question Assignment 1 (5 points) 

Let f  be a function given by  $f(x)=x^{3}+\pi x+4$
```

…you have to give the points as option, and let the class do the formating (and you'll be able to change the presentation in an homogenous way easely later)

```latex
\question[5] Assignment 1 

Let f  be a function given by  $f(x)=x^{3}+\pi x+4$
```

…also questions are automatically numbered, and you don't have to manage the numbering by yourself when you rearange later

```latex
\question[5]  

Let f  be a function given by  $f(x)=x^{3}+\pi x+4$
```

From here, I understand that you want the numbering to be prefixed with “Assignment” and to be bolded. Here comes `qformat{Format Specification}` to customise question number lines. Class documentation says that:

> Format specification must contain some stretchability (e.g., at least one `\hfill` or `\dotfill` or `\hrulefill` or ...) and can contain the commands
>
> - `\thequestion`, which expands to the question number,
> - `\thequestiontitle`, which expands to
>
>   - the title of the question, if this question was defined using a `\titledquestion` command instead of a `\question` command, or
>   - the number of the question, if this question was defined using a `\question` command,
> - `\thepoints`, which expands to
>
>   - the number of points followed by the argument to the last `\pointname` command, if there were points specified for the question, or
>   - nothing, if no points were specified for the question
> - `\totalpoints`, which expands to the total number of points specified for the question and all of its parts, subparts, and subsubparts. The command `\totalpoints` expands to `\pointsofquestion{\arabic{question}}`.

OK, so something like the following will do the trick (checked/compiled with `pdflatex`)

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam} % 'twoside' when printing
%\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,twoside]{geometry}
%\linespread{1.3}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % UTF-8 input
%\usepackage[english]{babel}             % Set language to english
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\title{Adding titles in exam class}
\author{F.O}
\date{Apr 10, 2022 at 16:15}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{PART~\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  %\tableofcontents
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \qformat{\textbf{Assignment~\thequestion}\quad(\thepoints)\hfill}
    
  \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth ]
    \section{Without help tools}
  \end{tcolorbox}

  \begin{questions}
    \question[5] 

      Let $f$ be a function given by  $f(x)=x^{3}+\pi x+4$
      \begin{parts}
        \part foo
        \part bar
        \part baz
      \end{parts}
    \question[5]

      \begin{parts}
        \part fiz
        \part boo
        \part buz
      \end{parts}
  \end{questions}

  \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth ]
    \section{With help tools}    
  \end{tcolorbox}
  \begin{questions}
    \question[5]

      Let $f$ be a function given by  $f(x)=x^{3}+\pi x+4$
      \begin{parts}
        \part alpha
        \part beta
        \part charlie
      \end{parts}
    \question[5]

      \begin{parts}
        \part delta
        \part echo
        \part fiona
      \end{parts}
  \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Note that you should [use `titlesec` to refine formatting by centring part+number and going to new line before text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273024/23418). You should also [consider creating a command for the titles in box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/526839/23418). Hope that helps.

Comment: Nice, but your code can‘t compile when copied. Can you please make it complete? Thank you

Comment: Well, there was some errors in your post (I mean it won't compile either) and I've added another one by putting `\newline` in the counter redefinition. Corrected and full preamble added now.

Answer (score 0):

According to the `exam` class manual the commands `\part`, `\section` etc are available (the class is built on the `article` class so `\chapter` is not included).

What, if anything, did you try?

Comment: I just added a picture for the format I want .

Comment: @F.O OK, you have shown what you want. What did you try with the `exam` class, not the `report` class?

Comment: I just modified the question and added what I tried.